# Code executes from Chrome Console but not from Userscript

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title states I've tried running the following code through Userscript to no avail. The "Starting" alert pops up and then nothing happens, nothing in console and no clicks occur. I've checked if jQuery is loaded and it is. Running the code through console only works when the Userscript still contains the definition for '$', otherwise it runs fine through just console. The website I am trying to run this on is using jQuery version 1.11.1, is this a problem since I am loading the latest?

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name         Powerball Bot
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Beat the odds
// @author       Me.
// @match        http://vladgotlib.com/powerball/
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(function(){
    var rect;
    alert('Starting');
    var $=jQuery.noConflict();
    setInterval(function() {
        var rect = $('#' + 'r_w' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 39) + 'h' +Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + '_');
        rect.click();
    }, 100)
});
```

I've been using the following snippet to run it through console:

```
setInterval(function() {
        var rect = $('#' + 'r_w' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 39) + 'h' +Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + '_');
        rect.click();
    }, 100)
```

Comment: `$(function(){` you start off with `$` being assumed to be jQuery but *inside* you do `var $=jQuery.noConflict();` how is that supposed to work?

Comment: Add `console.log()`s, (Google how to view console.log's from an extension). Ensure the correct element is being accessed. You may need to set scope to the unsafeWindow.

Comment: @FrankerZ you should be getting logs normally from a userscript. At least I've never had to do anything when writing a userscript to enable them. Unless the userscript extension itself does something but I've also done it with Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey and Violentmonkey.

Comment: @vlaz What is Violentmonkey? It sounds like something that would come and kill my family if I used it.

Comment: @FrankerZ when a programmer writes too many bugs the violent monkeys are released to "deal" with them once and for all.  :) It's the newest (I think) extension that handles userscripts.

Comment: @FrankerZ I had console.log()'s before but removed them for this latest version. I added it back and the interval Function is running and spamming up console with my message. I also included the object in it and it's just saying 'Clicking: [object Object]'.

Comment: @vlaz All I know is that when I remove the $ from infront of the (function() { the code stops working at all and without the $=jQuery.noConflict(); even the console version doesn't work. No errors ever appear.

Comment: So `console.log(rect)` before the click, is returning the rectangle correctly?

Comment: @FrankerZ I guess, it doesn't actually link me to the object but it does function

Comment: You should just simply call your function like: `(function($){ /* Use $ here */ })(jQuery)`

Comment: @ShaunWibster What exactly does that mean?

Comment: Interesting development. Disabling the script and then entering into console still works.

Comment: @FrankerZ Previously when I've console.log'd objects it gives the full element in the console and when I hover over it highlights on the page. With this it's just reading out as [object Object] for every console.log.

Comment: `console.log(rect.length)` and see if it's > 0

Comment: @FrankerZ The length is 1, but I solved the User script not running problem and posted my solution below. Shouldn't the length be 0 if there's only 1 object?

Comment: The object is an array (Well, it's more of a jQuery type array), that has a `.length` property and can be iterated over.

Answer (score 0):

So, my comment about the jQuery version turned out to be more relevant than I thought. Using @vlaz and @FrankerZ 's advice to call the function with:

```
(function($){

})(jQuery);
```

and removing the:

```
var $=jQuery.noConflict();
```

and:

```
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
```

Totally solved the problem.